# Animation not getting attached to markers correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/373/

I'm trying to wrap up the maps api in a little module I can just pass an array of objects it will use to draw markers on the map.

The code below works except that the animation ( toggleBounce() ) is only attached to one of the markers drawn on the map. When I click any of the markers the same marker bounces. It must be a problem with how the click listener is being attached, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My module:

```
var gmapsModule = (function () {

    //private

    function toggleBounce(marker) {
        console.dir(marker);
        //make markers bounce when selected
        if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
    }

    function drawMarkers( mapOptions, branchMarkers, animation ) {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        for (var prop in branchMarkers) {

            if( branchMarkers.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {

                var branch = branchMarkers[prop];

                var markerCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(branch.lat,branch.lng);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    //icon: markerImageOptions,
                    position: markerCoordinates,
                    title: branch.branchname
                });

                //draw marker on map
                marker.setMap(map);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', animation(marker));

            } //end if
        } // end for

    }

    //public
    return {
        drawMarkers: drawMarkers,
        toggleBounce: toggleBounce
    };
})();
```

Using the module to generate the map

```
var branchObjs = [
    { 
        branchname: 'sssssssssss',
        branchnum: '1',
        lat: '20.804167',
        lng: '-53.169444'
    },
    { 
        branchname: 'oooooooooo',
        branchnum: '2',
        lat: '20.824167',
        lng: '-53.189444'
    }
];

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.804167,-53.169444),
    zoom: 9
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',
    gmapsModule.drawMarkers(mapOptions,branchObjs,gmapsModule.toggleBounce));
```

Comment: `branchObjs` is not defined.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: gmapsModule.drawMarkers is not a function`. Second request: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Whoops forgot I changed that. Just fixed it.

Comment: I'll edit it again to remove my getIcon.php script, even though thats not the source of the problem.

Comment: @geocodezip I cleaned it up and added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep references to *all* the markers and toggle the animation state of each one.  Currently you only keep a reference to the last, so that is the only one you can change.

```
var gmapsModule = (function () {

  //private
  markers = [];

  function toggleBounce() {
      //make the clicked marker bounce
      if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
          this.setAnimation(null);
      } else {
          this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
      }
      }
  }
```

// ----------------------------------------------------

```
if (branchMarkers.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

    var branch = branchMarkers[prop];

    var markerCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(branch.lat, branch.lng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        //icon: markerImageOptions,
        position: markerCoordinates,
        title: branch.branchname
    });
    gmapsModule.markers.push(marker);  // keep reference to marker
```

// ----------------------------------------------------

[updated fidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/375/)

Comment: hmm when I tried that jsfiddle ALL the markers bounce when I click on one of them. I was attempting to make just the marker clicked on bounce.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood you question.  Updated answer/fiddle to make just the clicked marker bounce.